# Multiple On select change Ajax Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I work on Laravel 5.2 and I generate a table, using a foreach loop on my employees, with list of employees like this :

```
ID Name Team Category
1  toto t1   select
2  tata t1   select
3  titi t2   select
```

With "select" an input type select with the list of available categories.
When I change the category in the select I want to insert a new line in my table "category_relation" with the employee's id and the category selected.

My question is : When a select change, how can I get the correct ID and category in ajax and send them to my function store in my controller ?

Thanks all

EDIT : I tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".selectCategory").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST', 
            url: '/employee/changecateg', 
            data: {'id' : $('input.employee_id').val(), 'categ' : $('select.selectCategory').val()}, 
            success: function(response){ 
                console.log(response); 
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

And my employees list :

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'url' => action('AffectAbcController@store')]) !!}
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped m-b-none datatable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="no-sort">Photo</th>
                <th>Entrée</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Prénom</th>
                <th>Site</th>
                <th>Pôle</th>
                <th>Equipe</th>    
                <th class="no-sort">Tél interne</th>
                <th>Affecter catégorie</th> 
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            @foreach ($personnels as $personnel)
            <?php $i++ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_ETAT}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_DATE_ENTREE }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_NOM_USAGE}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_PRENOM }} </td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->site["SITE_LIBELLE"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->pole["POLE_LIBELLE"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->equipe["EQUIPE_LIBELLE"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_TELEPHONE}}</td>
                    <td> 
                        <input type="hidden" class="employee_id" name="HISTO_AFFECT_ID_PERSONNEL" value="{{$personnel->PERSO_ID_PERSONNEL}}"/>
                        <select class="form-input selectCategory" name="HISTO_AFFECT_ID_CATEG">
                            <option value="0"></option>
                            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                @if(isset($personnel->lastAbc[0]))
                                    @if($personnel->lastAbc[0]["HISTO_AFFECT_ID_CATEG"]==$category->CATEG_ID_ABC)
                                        <option value='{{$category->CATEG_ID_ABC}}' selected="selected">{{$category->CATEG_CODE_ABC}} - {{$category->CATEG_LIBELLE_ABC }}</option>
                                    @else
                                        <option value='{{$category->CATEG_ID_ABC}}'>{{$category->CATEG_CODE_ABC}} - {{$category->CATEG_LIBELLE_ABC }}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @else
                                    <option value='{{$category->CATEG_ID_ABC}}'>{{$category->CATEG_CODE_ABC}} - {{$category->CATEG_LIBELLE_ABC }}</option>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </select>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    </form>
```

The problem is all select have the same class, so when i get it I often have the first select value even if I change an other.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
data: {'id' : $('input.employee_id').val(), 'categ' : $('select.selectCategory').val()},
```

To

```
data: {'id' : $(this).siblings('input.employee_id').val(), 'categ' : $(this).val()},
```

`$(this)` is the current element in context (since it's a change on the select element, then `this` is the select element that's changed). Therefore we can use that to get the current element's selected value, and also the value of the nearest employee id box (using `.siblings()`).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you are unable to get the correct Hidden input value and Correct Select Box value.

You just have to change your JS a bit.

Make a variable inside your Select Change Event.

`var $td = $(this).parent();`

**Then inside Ajax :**

```
data: {
    'id' : $td.find('input.employee_id').val(), 
    'categ' : $td.find('select.selectCategory').val()
},
```

Hope this helps.